# Number of elements in Group_Concat

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is there a way to get the Counts of elements in Group_Concat? 
e.g When I tried

```
SELECT c.postcode
     , c.customerID
     , e.engforename
     , e.engsurname
     , j.jobbookeddate
     , p.conumber
     , j.type
     , GROUP_CONCAT(s.serialnumber) 
     , GROUP_CONCAT(fk_jbleID) 
  FROM ...
```

All I need is number of elements in a GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: I guess `COUNT( fk_jbleID )` and `COUNT(s.serialnumber)` will do the job

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT  *,
        LENGTH(C1) - LENGTH(REPLACE(C1, ',', ''))+1 AS Count_fk_jbleID,
        LENGTH(C2) - LENGTH(REPLACE(C2, ',', ''))+1 AS Count_fk_jbleID
FROM 
(
SELECT c.postcode
     , c.customerID
     , e.engforename
     , e.engsurname
     , j.jobbookeddate
     , p.conumber
     , j.type
     , GROUP_CONCAT(s.serialnumber)  AS C1
     , GROUP_CONCAT(fk_jbleID) AS C2
FROM Table1
) AS T
```